# Joomla: Fastest way to convert a ready html website to Joomla

Tags: html, joomla

I have made a couple of simple Joomla websites before. Those are using a custom template made by myself. They are easy websites as they have a simple linear menu, all pages have the same layout, just some articles are changing between pages.

But in my new project, I have a ready html website that I have to convert to Joomla. The problem is, there is no one repeating menu and there is no consistent layout. To simplify a bit: there are 10 pages and they all have different layouts. Between pages background changes, menu position changes, menu content changes, content box positions change, everything changes. This means I'm not able to do this site as I've done before, using one template index.php which simply contained my repeating page structure.

I am dreaming of a way to simply change ready_page1.html to ready_page1.php, adding some modules inside the php (which are then available for online editing, which is the reason switching to Joomla). I would do this to each page. The custom menus inside each page I would "manually" point to the according php files instead of the old html files. Is this method possible somehow? I couldn't figure out how to do this.

I don't care loosing lots of Joomla basic functionality due to this crude method, I just want the simplest way to do this.

In the end, I just want the exact same website I already have on html, but I want some chosen rectangular areas in the html pages to be editable Joomla modules. The modules would have the pen icon for editing. That's it, no other functionality is necessary.

Comment: Could you give some screenshots so you can define "different" to us of the existing layouts. It might be you can do something clever with conditional layout blocks in the template.

Comment: Based mainly on your final paragraph, have you considered using an alternative CMS, more suitable to that requirement? Something like either [Perch](http://grabaperch.com/) or [kirby](http://getkirby.com) would be quite a good fit.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the site you are converting is a usability nightmare. Consistency is part of giving the user a positive experience. That said, if you have to make it exactly the same, then the easiest way is to do it the right way to begin with.

First, you need to learn about page class suffixes. You can add those to a menu item so that you can control the CSS on a per page basis. This will allow you to change backgrounds and other elements on each page.

Documentation - http://docs.joomla.org/Page_Class_Suffix

Next, you will need to make a template so that each of the module positions is collapsible. If you plan out the positions, you should be able to use a single index.php for the entire site. We have a custom template that we use for every site we do and it rarely needs to be touched because all of the positions we would possibly want to use are already there, they just don't get used until a module is put in the position.

Documentation - http://docs.joomla.org/Collapsing_columns

You will also want to make sure you understand menu assignments. You should be able to assign the modules to the pages as needed to create the layout you want for each page. If you are using 2.5.x, then you can probably get by with the built in menu assignment features. If you are using 1.5.x then (you really should upgrade) you will probably want to use [Advanced Module Manager](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager) as it makes menu assignments much easier and more flexible.

Documentation - http://docs.joomla.org/Help15:Screen.modules.edit.15#Menu_Assignment

Once you get a good grasp of how Joomla templates work and how they are supposed to be used you will find that you can basically do anything you want within the framework so you don't lose any functionality.

Answer (score 1):

1. build your website and create those 10 pages (contents, heirarcy, and so on..).
2. then create your templates based on those html files. this is where you adapt the html into a joomla template. after this step, you should end up with at most 10 templates depending on your styles (crude but quick)
3. as far as i know and [from the documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Help17%3aExtensions_Template_Manager_Styles_Edit), Joomla 1.7 supports "template per page" (see the screenshot). you can pick out which style will be applied to which item. it even applies to subpages. [another documentation here](http://docs.joomla.org/index.php?title=How_do_you_assign_a_template_to_a_specific_page%3F&oldid=31167)

Comment: Thank you, I am now in the process of using this method. I am doing it by modifying the original Beez2 template. What might be the correct way of avoiding the multiplication of all 120 files of the Beez2 template? Only index.php needs to change per template, so it's an overkill to copy all 120 files for each template. I have all the variations in one css file.

Comment: you can build from scratch. as far as i know, you only need at least 2 files for a template: the xml for the installation details, and the index which will be the template. you will not need the rest of the "junk". here's a link for creating templates. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/creating-your-first-joomla-template/